# Plot multiple lines in a for loop in d3

Tags: d3.js, svg, plot

There are many cases online how to plot couple of lines in d3 if you add svg object only once, such as

```
   svg.selectAll("line")
   .data(dataset)
   .enter().append("line")
   .style("stroke", "black")  // colour the line
   .attr("x1", function(d) { console.log(d); return xScale(d.x1); })
   .attr("y1", function(d) { return yScale(d.y1); })
   .attr("x2", function(d) { return xScale(d.x2); })
   .attr("y2", function(d) { return yScale(d.y2); });
```

This plot create one line. I want to create many different lines in an array smth like

```
   var svg = d3.select("body")
   .append("svg")
   .attr("width", w)
   .attr("height", h);

   for (a_ind=1; a_ind<3; a_ind++){
   dataset_a=dataset.filter(function(d) { return (d.a==a_ind)})

   svg.selectAll("line")
   .data(dataset_a) - //!!! using new dataset in each cycle
   .enter().append("line")
   .style("stroke", "black")  // colour the line
   .attr("x1", function(d) { console.log(d); return xScale(d.x1); })
   .attr("y1", function(d) { return yScale(d.y1); })
   .attr("x2", function(d) { return xScale(d.x2); })
   .attr("y2", function(d) { return yScale(d.y2); }); 
   }
```

I was told it's impossible. Or maybe there is the way? And also how to access then line from dataset_a if i want to delete it with the click of the mouse?

Comment: Its possible, but your [data has to be structured the right way](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/8XLzUYLoFnY). Basically, your data has to be in the form of `[[objects line 1], [objects line 2], ...]`

Comment: @Anna K and pmkro: Just to clarify, That structure is necessary for plotting multiple paths, not multiple lines, as I mentioned in my [other comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49281258/plot-multiple-lines-in-a-for-loop-in-d3#comment85582397_49282928).

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you want to plot lines, I suggest that you append...`<line>`s!

The thing with a D3 enter selection is quite simple: the number of appended elements is the number of objects in the data array that doesn't match any element.

So, you just need a data array with several objects. For instance, let's create 50 of them:

```
var data = d3.range(50).map(function(d) {
  return {
    x1: Math.random() * 300,
    x2: Math.random() * 300,
    y1: Math.random() * 150,
    y2: Math.random() * 150,
  }
});
```

And, as in the below demo I'm selecting `null`, all of them will be in the enter selection. Here is the demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var data = d3.range(50).map(function(d) {
  return {
    x1: Math.random() * 300,
    x2: Math.random() * 300,
    y1: Math.random() * 150,
    y2: Math.random() * 150,
  }
});
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);
var lines = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("line")
  .attr("x1", function(d) {
    return d.x1
  })
  .attr("x2", function(d) {
    return d.x2
  })
  .attr("y1", function(d) {
    return d.y1
  })
  .attr("y2", function(d) {
    return d.y2
  })
  .style("stroke", function(_, i) {
    return color(i)
  })
  .style("stroke-width", 1);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Finally, a tip: as this is JavaScript you can use `for` loops anywhere you want. However, **do not** use `for` loops to append elements in a D3 code. It's unnecessary and not idiomatic.

That being said, whoever told you that it is *impossible* was wrong, it's clearly possible. Here is a demo (but don't do that, it's a very cumbersome and ugly code):

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var data = d3.range(50).map(function(d, i) {
  return {
    x1: Math.random() * 300,
    x2: Math.random() * 300,
    y1: Math.random() * 150,
    y2: Math.random() * 150,
    id: "id" + i
  }
});
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

  var filteredData = data.filter(function(d) {
    return d.id === "id" + i
  });

  var lines = svg.selectAll(null)
    .data(filteredData)
    .enter()
    .append("line")
    .attr("x1", function(d) {
      return d.x1
    })
    .attr("x2", function(d) {
      return d.x2
    })
    .attr("y1", function(d) {
      return d.y1
    })
    .attr("y2", function(d) {
      return d.y2
    })
    .style("stroke", function() {
      return color(i)
    })
    .style("stroke-width", 1);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this. Make each data set (1 data set per line), [an array inside the final data array](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/8XLzUYLoFnY) `.enter().append()` will then work properly. To remove the line on click, I added an event handler that will select the line just clicked and remove it.

```
var data = [[dataset_a], [dataset_b], [dataset_c], [dataset_d], [dataset_e]];

var xValue = function(d){return d.x;}
var yValue = function(d){return d.y;}

var lineFunction = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) { return xScale(xValue(d)); })
  .y(function(d) { return yScale(yValue(d)); });

var lines = d3.select("svg").selectAll("path")

lines.data(data)
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("d", lineFunction)
  .on("click", function(d){
    d3.select(this).remove();
  });
```

Comment: No worries, might want to accept so its show as completed.

Comment: @pmkro Nice answer, always nice to see new folks in the d3 world on SO. I hope you don't mind, I've edited it to change the snippet to a plain code block (as snippets are generally for working code demonstrations).

Comment: @pmkro it's worth mentioning that you're appending paths, not lines. Also, that being the case, OP doesn't need an array with inner arrays of data.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado ahh yes. I usually just use paths, forgot about lines!