# D3 iterating over selected JSON columns

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, iteration

I have a JSON dataset:

```
var data =[
{ "date":"1-May-12","A":68.13,"B":34.12, "C": 33},
{ "date":"30-Apr-12","A":63.98,"B":95.56, "C": 33},
{ "date":"27-Apr-12","A":67.00,"B":57.89, "C": 33},
{ "date":"26-Apr-12","A":89.70,"B":48.54, "C": 33},
{ "date":"25-Apr-12","A":99.00,"B":29.23, "C": 33},
{ "date":"24-Apr-12","A":130.28,"B":99.23, "C": 33},
{ "date":"23-Apr-12","A":166.70,"B":101.34, "C": 33},
{ "date":"20-Apr-12","A":234.98,"B":122.34, "C": 33},
{ "date":"21-Apr-12","A":345.44,"B":134.56, "C": 33},
{ "date":"24-Apr-12","A":130.28,"B":99.23, "C": 33},
{ "date":"25-Apr-12","A":166.70,"B":101.34, "C": 33},
{ "date":"24-Apr-12","A":234.98,"B":122.34, "C": 33},
{ "date":"19-Apr-12","A":345.44,"B":134.56, "C": 33},
{ "date":"18-Apr-12","A":443.34,"B":160.45, "C": 33},
{ "date":"17-Apr-12","A":543.70,"B":180.34, "C": 33},
{ "date":"16-Apr-12","A":580.13,"B":210.23, "C": 33},
{ "date":"13-Apr-12","A":605.23,"B":223.45, "C": 33},
{ "date":"12-Apr-12","A":622.77,"B":201.56, "C": 33},
{ "date":"11-Apr-12","A":626.20,"B":212.67, "C": 33},
{ "date":"10-Apr-12","A":628.44,"B":310.45, "C": 33},
];
```

Currently to if I want to add columns (such as A and C) to a line graph I have to do the following code

```
//add column data to domain max field

max =Math.max(d.A, d.C);
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return max})]);

//generate lines
var valuelineA = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.A); });

var valuelineC = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.C); });

//add paths
svg.append("path")      
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", valuelineA(data));

svg.append("path")     
        .attr("class", "line")
        .style("stroke", "red")
        .attr("d", valuelineC(data));
```

Lets say I have an array with column names (like `yVals =["A","B"]`) is there a good way to iterate over them using something like the `foreach` loop so I do not need to copy and paste code and change variables?

Comment: Something you could try is modifying your data into the form `[[date & A], [date & B], [date & C]]` where each of the inner arrays is filled with `{date: date, value:(A/B/C val)}` then do [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49281258/plot-multiple-lines-in-a-for-loop-in-d3/49282928#49282928) to plot all the lines.

Comment: @pmkro Ok I like your solution since it is clean and only uses `.append()` and `.enter()`. But one of the issues I am having is trying to understand how to select the data columns individually  would I do something like `d["COLUMN_NAME"]`?

Comment: [Something like this](https://jsfiddle.net/p7z2pwLd/3/). Your data structure actually changes. Fiddle is for bigger code section.

Comment: @pmkro so there is not a good way to refractor the data mapping code? The issue I have is if I have n columns it would still be copy/paste code but a lot less

Comment: I would put the data mapping into a function and then loop over all the possible keys each time returning its array and pushing into the final data array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L45vjq8L/) with a final solution. Create a function that transposes data into objects `{date, value}`. This creates data [that allows multiple lines to be entered nicely].(https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/8XLzUYLoFnY)

```
function changeData(data, keyIn){
    return data.map(function(d){
            var obj = {};
            for(const key in d){
                if(d.hasOwnProperty(key)  && ["date", keyIn].includes(key)){ 
                    if(key == "B"){obj.value = d[key]}
                    else{obj[key] = d[key];} 
                }
            }
            return obj;
        });
}
```

Then create your lines with

```
var lineFunc = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.value); });

var lines = svg.selectAll("path").data(data)
    .enter().append("path")
  .attr("d", lineFunc);
```

If you open the console on the fiddle page it will ouput the final data structure.

I should also mention that if your data is large this will take a while in js and you might want to think about doing the data transformation server side if possible.